# Removing external dependencies to MFC DLL project

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, dependencies, external

Im developing a MFC DLL project in VS2008. 
The dll compiles OK and I can call it fine from an GUI exe that a contractor has developed for me. Visual C++ Redistributables are required to be installed for my dll (and maybe the exe which is developed in C++ too)

Another company wants to licence my dll to use with their C++ exe. They have requested that my dll have no external dependencies. Is it possible to compile my dll to remove all external dependencies like the Visual C++ Redistributables?

Does setting /MT do this?
I have read [Should I compile with /MD or /MT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757418/should-i-compile-with-md-or-mt) which makes some sense but I am concerned about dll hell.

Can this create issues with exe calling my dll? I read somewhere about that the exe and dll need to be using the same Visual C++ Redistributables or something.

I am somewhat new to C++. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can link with the static version of the CRT (yes, /MT) but it is quite dangerous.  You'll have to carefully review your exports.  Make very sure that none of them return C++ objects, not even an std::string (or CString).  Or any pointers that the client code has to release.  This will go wrong badly because the client will have its own CRT copy and use a different heap.  That will leak the returned object/pointer, crash the program on Vista and Win7 when their secure heap manager detects that the pointer doesn't belong to the heap.

It might be a matter of debate what exactly an 'external dependency' means.  Having a dependency on the CRT is not exactly external.  You will however have to supply them with a version of the DLL that was built on the same version of Visual Studio that they use.  The CRT can only be shared if the version matches.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you package all the dependent dlls into a installer package and release to your customer?

I have seen some of the software package does include the vc's dependent libraries....