# DLL should not require mfc dependency

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, mfc

Currently my DLL requires that mfc80u.dll and msvcr80.dll reside in the same directory when I want to use it from a different application.

I think there is a switch in VS2013 that somehow compiles the DLL in such a way that these files are no longer required.

I am pretty sure I have once read about it.

This makes the DLL much bigger, that to me that's worth it.

Does anybody know which switch that is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove VC runtime DLLs (not specific to MFC), use the `/MT` compiler switch. [image]

If you are using MFC, you must also use `Use MFC in Static Library` in General page of project settings.

Comment: This is correct, but [heed the warnings in this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3832092/2065121).