# Self-Extracting Zip: Specify Extraction Path With .exe File

Tags: c#, self-extracting

I'm working on a deployment plan for a C# Winforms application and would like to use a self-extracting .zip file to distribute all of the required files. Here is the file structure of the SFX:

Setup.exe
app.exe
app2.exe
readme.txt
manual.pdf

After the user runs the SFX, I want `Setup.exe` to take control and copy `app.exe`, `app2.exe`, `readme.txt`, and `manual.pdf` to location `x`. The path they are copied to will depend on choices the user makes from the UI of `Setup.exe`, system properties, etc.

How would I go about writing `Setup.exe` in C#?

Comment: Have you looked at using something like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) instead of writing your own installer?

Comment: @Chris I wish I could use NSIS, but for various reasons it is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I had very good experiences with using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) as a setup tool. It's a bit more than a SFX but really good to use, rather flexible and free-of-charge.

So I recommend that you do *not* write your own SFX in C# (aka "re-inventing the wheel") but rather use something existing that is real-world-proofen.

There are, of course, [a lot of other installers available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aInstallation_software).

Answer (score 0):

I agree, don't waste your time writing an installer when there are already ones available. If you did chose to write one on your own for whatever reason, I would encourage you to stay away from any languages that require dependencies (e.g. C# requires the .Net Runtime). I would suggest using C or C++ and turning on static linking using the [`/MT` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757418/should-i-compile-with-md-or-mt) so that your installer is dependent on as little as possible.

Some of the installation software I've used (in order of preference):

- **[Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)** - This is a free scripted installer which has a large user base including Firefox, DOSBox, 7-Zip, Winamp, and even Dropbox.
- **[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)** - This one is free, and the project files are setup more like an INI file. Overall, very easy to work with, but not as feature rich as NSIS. There is a visual editor called [ISTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) which makes it even easier to work with.
- **[Visual Studio Installer / Microsoft Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277513%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)** - It comes with Visual Studio, and it works well enough. It creates a MSI setup package.

See the  [list of installation software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) article on Wikipedia for other options.