# How to avoid including the same code when using C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, linker, include, static-libraries

*EDIT: I know about include guards, but include files are **not** the issue here. I'm talking about actual compiled and already linked code that gets baked into the static library.*

I'm creating a general-purpose utility library for myself in C++.

One of the functions I'm creating, `printFile`, requires `string`, `cout` and other such members of the standard library.

I'm worried that when the library is compiled, and then linked to another project that also uses `string` and `cout`, the code for `string` and `cout` will be duplicated: it will both be prelinked in the library binary the program is being linked with, and it will be again linked with the project that uses them itself.

The library is structured like this:

1. There is one `libname.hpp` file the programmer who uses the library is supposed to `#include` in his projects.
2. For every function `fname` declared in `libname.hpp`, there is an file `fname.cpp` implementing it.
3. All `fname.cpp` files also `#include "libname.hpp"`.
4. The library itself compiles into `libname.a` which is copied to `/usr/lib/`.

Will this even happen? 
If yes, is it a problem at all? 
If yes, then how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm worried that when the library is compiled, and then linked to another project that also uses string and cout, the code for string and cout will be duplicated

Don't worry: no modern compilation system will do that. The code for template functions is emitted into object files, but the linker discards duplicate entries.

Answer (score 3):

The library definitions of the standard C++ library won't show up in your own statically library unless you explicitly include them there (i.e., you extract object files from the standard C++ library and include them into your library). Static libraries are not linked at all and will just have undefined references to other libraries. A static library is merely a collection of object files defining the symbols provided by the library. The definitions which come from the headers, e.g., inline functions and template instantiations, will be defined in such a way that multiple definitions in multiple translation units won't conflict. Where the code isn't actually inlined, it will define "weak" symbols which result in duplicates being ignored or removed at link time.

The only real concern is that the libraries linked into an executable need to use compatible library definitions. With substantial amount of code residing in header files, there are relatively frequent changes to the C++ header files, including standard C++ library headers (relative to the C library headers which contain a lot less code).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code for standard library things will be duplicated. It can be a problem if for example you return a std::string or take one as a parameter in one of your methods. It may have a different layout in your standard library implementation than in the user's.

Comment: OK, I understand. However, "how to avoid this" is a big part of my question.

Comment: I now realize that I was mixing two different issues: code duplication and standard library class layouts. The second is not an issue if you're compiling your program with the same compiler you used to compile the library, which appears to be your case. As for the first, it may result in larger code but is not really a problem otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is rarely a problem in practice.

For `static` functions and inline templated functions defined in header files, there's nothing to worry about: every compilation unit gets its own copy (e.g. within the `.a` library there may already be many anonymous copies).  This is okay because these definitions aren't exported, so the linker doesn't need to worry about them.

For functions that are declared with non-static linkage, whether you have an issue depends on how you link the `.a` library.

When you build the library, you typically will *not* link in the standard C++ library.  The created library will contain undefined references to the standard C++ library.  These must be resolved before building the final executable binary.  This is normally done automatically when linking that final binary in the default way (depending on the compiler).

There are times when people do link in the standard C++ library into a static library.  If you're linking against multiple static libraries that each embed another library (like the standard C++ library), then expect trouble if there are any differences in those embedded libraries.  Fortunately, this is a rare problem, at least with the `gcc` toolchain.  It's a [more frequent problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757537/25050) with Microsoft's tools.

In some cases, a workaround is to make one or more conflicting static libraries into a dynamic library.  This way each of these dynamic libraries can statically link its own copy of the problematic library.  As long as the dynamic library doesn't export the symbols from the problematic library and there are no memory layout incompatibilities, there generally isn't any trouble.