# Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) vs Multi-threaded (/MT)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

My VC++ MFC solution includes four project.

1. Two project build as DLLs
2. One project build as Static Lib
3. One project build as exe with using above three libraries.

I need to host this application without CLR support in windows XP.  so I use configuration  `Use of MFC` as `Use MFC in a Static Library` in all four project.

So my question is what should be the `C++-> Code Genaration` Configuration for each project.

Comment: Should I compile with /MD or /MT? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757418/should-i-compile-with-md-or-mt

Comment: @Pheonix: thank you and I read this. Logically DLL should use /MD and Lib and Exe should use /MT. But my application gets some linking error. `error LNK2005: __encode_pointer already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll)`. I think because static lib already include with a MSVCRT.lib. So this is quit conflicts. So I need some direct answer if some one there clearly understand this concept. I think there should be some straight forward rule for this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use /MD for all your projects. As is stated in the referenced questions: it is important to be consistent. So: even build your Static Lib using /MD, since it will be used in an /MD executable.
When you do this, the linker doesn't try to link two different versions of the Microsoft library (static and dynamic) which resolves the error.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. So I just reduce my application for one exe and one Dll for testing purpose. both build as Use `MFC in a Static Library` and `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)`, but didn't run in windows XP. but running in windows 7 visual studio installed computer.