# visual studio 2013 options

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries

If .lib files are for static linking and .dll files for dynamic linking why can I specify in C/C++ -> code generation -> runtime library options select multi threaded or multithreaded DLL when building an explicitly static library (ie when making a .lib) or when building a project and linking to a .lib library?

Comment: This setting is for the runtime which is independent of the target that you are producing. What I mean by that is you can create a static .lib with a dynamic CRT or a dll with a static CRT and several other combinations..

Comment: What, exactly, is CRT and when would I want to make it static or dynamic? I want to statically link my libraries, is that guaranteed if it is a .lib file either way? Runtime setting must match across all libraries right?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio allows you to specify how the [CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) is going to be integrated into your project under `C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library`. This project setting controls how C/C++ routines used explicitly or internally (e.g. exception functions or STL routines) are going to be linked to your project.

You can create a static library which uses the CRT dynamically or statically by specifying the `/MT` or `/MD` flag during compilation.

Regarding advantages/disadvantages I'm linking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757537/1938163) which features a pretty good list of points to keep in mind.

One last thing to notice: if your project is going to use multiple static libraries (including your .lib file), you should make sure that this CRT option matches during the linking phase otherwise you might encounter [the (in)famous LNK4098 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007312/resolving-lnk4098-defaultlib-msvcrt-conflicts-with).