# Some computers report missing certain DLL errors when using objectbox. DLL

Tags: objectbox

Cannot start this program because CVRuntime140D.dll is missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to resolve the problem

Comment: Can you pin down which Window version lack this? I was under the impression that Windows 10 installs these dependency automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the Microsoft Visual C++

Download the below

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I want to compile the program to run without installing Microsoft Visual.I would like to ask the author to set the selected runtime to MT mode when compiling the DLL to solve the above problem

Comment: You would need to ask the author to give you the code. However, this is unlikely unless you know the author or use the software for corporate license etc. The download does not install a version of visual studio, it is a package required for C++ programs. I imagine that the program is using C++ and will require this anyway. Installing it on users machines / your machine will have no adverse effects.

Comment: ObjectBox.dll is provided by the author, but this DLL is compiled in MD mode, and running on some computers may cause an error with missing DLLs.To avoid this, I can only think of using MT mode to compile objectbox.dll to solve this problem.It was also my first time to use someone else's DLL and download objectbox. DLL directly from GitHub.Don't know that  need a company license to use objectbox. DLL

Comment: if opensource like github then you will not. How ever this sounds like its a C++ issue. I can't comment on MT mode or if it will work as I don't know what application your using. How ever just like python won't run with out python installed. You can't run C++ libarys or DLL's with out C++ installed. I would recommend installing.

Comment: Btw, MD vs MT is not a straightforward decision. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757418/should-i-compile-with-md-or-mt for some advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: objectbox. DLL uses other DLLs when it is used, ObjectBox.dll compiled using MD mode requires the necessary DLLs on the computer. ObjectBox.dll compiled using MT mode can run without the associated DLLs on the computer. Because the program is written to be used by others, there is no guarantee that the customer's computer has the required environment installed.

Comment: Because I am a new hand, this is the only solution I can find for the time being

Comment: Btw, if you want to support old Windows versions as well, you might get away to grab the dlls from the redistributable and place them along with the objectbox.dll without installation. Haven't verified though.

Comment: i've got away with that a few times but it is mostly hit or miss if it will work. Also ensure you don't just grab it from the internet, grab it from a old windows machine

Comment: Thank you. I really don't know much about MD and MT modes. I will learn the difference between them after the problem is solved

Comment: Yes, I tried putting the required DLLs together with objecbox. DLL, but those DLLs needed to use other DLLs, which didn't feel realistic to implement

Comment: Maybe it is the first time to use DLL, and I feel a lot of problems with it